# How do I pipe HTML form input into PHP and then to Ruby?

Tags: php, html, ruby, nginx, raspberry-pi

This probably seems stupid. If it's non-achievable, please let me know.
So: I have a Rasperry Pi (RPi) that's running Raspbian and nginx for a simple home network fileshare server. I mainly did this for learning, and dived straight into it. Anyway, my login system is as follows:

login.html:

```
<html>
...
<form action="cgi-bin/loginHandler.php">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input name="username">
    <br/>
    <label for="username">Password:</label>
    <input name="password">
    <input name="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
...
</html>
```

cgi-bin/loginHandler.php:

```
<?php
exec("./login.rb $arg1 $arg2")
?>
```

cgi-bin/login.rb:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
#update-alternatives changed "ruby" to "ruby1.9.1"

cmdArray = Array.new

ARGV.each do |a|
    cmdArray.push a
end

#backwards because I used push
if cmdArray[1] == "/u/afdsadf" and cmdArray[0] == "/r/unixporn"
    htmlFile = File.new("loggedIn.html", "w+")
    htmlFile.puts("<html><head></head><body>You are now logged in!</body></html>")
else
    htmlFile = File.new("notLoggedIn.html", "w+")
    htmlFile.puts("<html><head></head><body>You are now logged in!</body></html>")
end
```

I checked my cgi-bin directory, where there definitely was not a "loggedIn.html" or "notLoggedIn.html", so either the Ruby is throwing an error or not running at all. Then again, using PHP was probably a bad idea in the first place. I also probably need a `method` in the form itself, but I wouldn't know what to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use absolute paths instead:

```
exec("/path/to/login.rb $arg1 $arg2")
```

Or explicitly call ruby:

```
exec("/usr/bin/ruby /path/to/login.rb $arg1 $arg2")
```

Same for the files you try to open:

```
htmlFile = File.new("/path/to/loggedIn.html", "w+")
htmlFile = File.new("/path/to/notLoggedIn.html", "w+")
```